# What went in creating www.christmas.jackdaniels.com

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm learning the basics of Jquery, HTML5 and CSS3. Just crossed this website http://christmas.jackdaniels.com/
It seems to have a zoom in kind of effect when interacted with an element. Any idea how this is done? I saw the source code of the site, but it looks totally greek.

regards,
Sabharish

Comment: the zoom effect is a video [http://christmas.jackdaniels.com/video/ie9.mp4](http://christmas.jackdaniels.com/video/ie9.mp4) they just play it and then add a background image [http://christmas.jackdaniels.com/img/tree.jpg](http://christmas.jackdaniels.com/img/tree.jpg)

Comment: oh..never thought it was a video. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, they are using the html5 tag `<map></map>`

More information can be found here:

http://www.html-5-tutorial.com/map-and-area-elements.htm

HTML5 Specs of the Map tag can be found here:

http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/map

Comment: Thanks for the response. Any idea how that zoom in effect is done? Is that by some JS framework or is it WebGL.

Comment: I'd dare say it might be a JS framework, but I have no proof of it. I know WebGL is capable of doing amazing things.